# ACF Field Group Relationships - How to output a certain relationship value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 3 custom post types:

- Team Member
- Team Group
- Service

Each CPT have own Field Group in ACF as below:

- Team Member (related_team_member)
- Team Group (related_team_group)
- Service (related_service)

All those fields are connected by relationship in ACF, so structure looks like this

John Doe -> Photography -> Location Shoots, Studio Shoots, Retouching 
John Doe -> Videography -> Basic Filming, Drone Shoots, Postproduction

So, to explain this, one of the team members belongs to both groups Photography and Videography and he provides 6 services, 3 different services for each group.

Now, I have a few pages where I would like to output the team members data.

**single-team-members.php**

I'm outputting single team member data here, so on John's Doe card I have his Picture, Name, Groups he belong to (Photography, Videography) and all services he provides and this is done. A bit simplified while loop below:

```
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post(); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <h3 class="member-group"><?php
                    $relatedGroups = get_field('related_group');
                        if ($relatedGroups) {
                            echo '<ul class="member-group__list">';
                            foreach($relatedGroups as $group) { ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($group); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($group); ?></a><span class="member-group__divider">,&nbsp</span></li>
                        <?php
                            } echo '</ul>';
                        }?>
                </h3>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                <?php
                    $relatedServices = get_field('related_service');
                        if ($relatedServices) {
                            echo '<ul>';
                        foreach($relatedServices as $service) { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($service); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($service); ?></a></li>
                    <?php }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }?>
     <?php }
```

**page-all-team.php**

Here I have all team members cards where each card have outputted Picture, Name and the Group they belong to and here I outputted all groups they belongs to so for John is "Photography, Videography"

```
$relatedTeamMembers = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'team-member',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'related_team_group',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        'value' => array()
    )
    )
));

if ($relatedTeamMembers->have_posts()) {
        while($relatedTeamMembers->have_posts()) {
            $relatedTeamMembers->the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="team-member">
                    <div class="team-member__label-gold">
                        <div class="team-member__label-gold__name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                        <div class="team-member__label-gold__service">
                            <?php
                            $groups = get_field('related_team_group');
                                foreach($groups as $group){
                                echo $group->post_title;
                                }?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></a>
        <?php }
}
```

**page-photography.php**

On this page I would like to output:

- services that John Doe offers in Photography group so: Location Shoots, Studio Shoots, Retouching
- Only one Group Name = Photography

**page-videography.php**
On this page I would like to output:

- services that John Doe offers in Videography group so: Basic Filming, Drone Shoots, Postproduction
- Only one Group Name = Videography

**page-aerial-shooting.php**
On this page I would like to output:

- Only one John's group = Videography
- Only two services he offers = Drone Shoots, Postproduction

Comment: The issue could a few things: the `foreach($services as $services)` you really need to change the second `$services` to the singular `$service`, otherwise you are using the whole `$services` array. Then I'm guessing that `$service` will be an `array` not an `object`, so you would do `echo $service['post_title'];` instead. If you change that second `$services` to the singular, and then `var_dump( $service )` just before the `echo` what do you get?

Comment: Thanks, that gave me an entire array for each service on the page

Comment: I think we need more information about what you are actually trying to do. _I would like to have a full control over what I'm outputting to the certain page._ - what page is this? Is this a Team Member detail page? You say you're getting an entire array, but we don't know what that is. Edit the question to include a more specific example and maybe a part of that array.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I have edited entire post so hope this is more clear but I have to simplified the code a bit as I was not able to past it fully here, I don't know why. And I'm sorry about my English maybe this is the reason why I'm not able to explain properly what I need :(

Answer (score 1):

When using the "post object" field of ACF, you will get a post object if you use the `get_field` function.

You can use the get_field function with the ID of the post, to get the field you want of this specific post (targeted by the ID). So if you want to output a field called "myfield" , you can use the IDs you got in the "post object" field.

Please notice to use a correct foreach loop, using `services` as `service` (single).

```
$services = get_field('related_service');
foreach($services as $service):
    $myfield = get_field('myfield', $service->ID); // using id of single post object
    echo $myfield;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you @rank and please excuse me beginners questions, but I don't think I understand this properly, so here instead `$myfield = get_field('myfield', $service->ID);` I should use an actual post object id like this? `$myfield = get_field('related_service', $service->135);` as this way I'm getting an error. I'm currently going through WP PHP course but not everything is super clear to me:( So thanks for helping me.

Comment: The operator `->` is for accessing attributes inside of objects. So the `ID` is an attribute inside of an post object. If your ACF field gives you an array of post objects (posts you selected for example in a dropdown), you can access the attribute using `->`. If you have the ID, you can do `get_field('myfield', 135);` to get the field value of "myfield" of the post with the id 135. If you are looping (foreach) post objects, you can access the ID of the specific post you are currently looping over (as $service) using `get_field('myfield', $service->ID);` .